# Simple xxx yyy { } CSS selector not working - why?

Tags: css

I have a seemingly simple html construct:

```
<div class="featured-image img-wrapper full-width">
  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=26">
    <img ... />
  </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to target the a (which unfortunately does not have its own class), so I use this CSS

```
.img-wrapper a {
  background-image:url(../images/bkgs/stripes_tiny_08.png);
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

but nothing happens to this a element! It's certainly not the background image itself, also tried a simple color. The weird thing is: there is another, similar construct further up on the page and there the selector works!
Firebug shows the following CSS paths (the target a is at the end)

```
working: html.js body.single div#page.wrap div#main-container.container div#primary.site-content div#content article#post-26.post-26 div.featured-image a.img-link
not wrk: html.js body.single div#page.wrap div#main-container.container div#primary.site-content div#content aside#yarpp_widget-2.widget div.bloglist article.post div.three div.featured-image a
```

I'm out of ideas. Haven't found any overriding CSS declarations. Any idea how I can target that a?

EDIT: the target a contains an img which has a :hover opacity set. That way I can see that the background color works, not the background image however

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r48ST/ It works. I'm assuming that your image isn't transparent and you can't see what's behind it, or that there's more in play with conflicting styles.

Comment: it's not .img-wrapper a img{ /* ... */ } ?

Comment: just opinion: add display:block; to .img-wrapper a

Comment: Sorry forgot one important detail: the a contains an img which has a :hover opacity set. That way I can see that the background color works, not the background image however. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: You mention the Firebug paths, but are you saying the selector is not even showing as ever applying to the element, or is it being crossed out (as shown when being overridden)?

Comment: @ScottS: it was not crossed out but showed as applied (at the top of the list).

Comment: Okay it works now. 
Miljan Puzovic was spot on in this comment:

"just opinion: add display:block; to .img-wrapper a"

Comment: Odd, is the `img` positioned absolutely or floated, causing the `a` to collapse to zero dimensions?

Comment: "img" element is positioned static, but you always must give display:block to "a" element if "img" element is inside of him. just expirience :)

Comment: no, the only styles that apply to the image are   .img-wrapper img {
    display: block;
}
img.scale-with-grid {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this effect? http://jsfiddle.net/r48ST/1/

[EDIT]: This is that effect http://jsfiddle.net/r48ST/2/ , just added some opacity on image. Also, put some transition effect on opacity an you have full effect.

Comment: No, actually this effect: http://labs.sevenspark.com/ when you hover over th eimage you see the stripes of the background image.

Comment: Thanks,a ctually your comment above about the display:block did the trick. Can you explain to me why? Other than in your jsfiddle, there is no width specified for the wrapper div

Comment: display:block guarantees that '<a>' element will be full over his children element in height an will have 100% width of parent element. Because of that, parent of '<a>' element (in this case .img-wrapper) must have limited width. If not, then parent of .img-wrapper must have limited width, or display:block of '<a>' element will cause that '<a>' element extends over 100% of first parent which have some limit of width. And in there is no such parent, it will have 100% width of body.

Answer (score 0):

remove img (if it's not transparent)

for conflicts:

- put !important at the end of css instruction.
- or try inline style.

Comment: I think his problem isn't that the style is being overridden, but rather that it's being applied behind the image element that is being wrapped.

Comment: img has a hover opacity of 0.5; also tried !important -> no change.

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying dimensions for your `<a>` tag, it will conform to the dimensions of the `<img>` tag that it contains. As such, any background image that you apply will be overlayed by the `<img>`. Putting repeat on only repeats the background image as many times ans it will fit (cropped or whole) within the element. If you give the element a width and a height greater than that of the image that it wraps you should see the background.

I hope this was the issue that you were facing. Otherwise, if you can post a bit more of your code or a demo we will be able to better help you.

EDIT: I just noticed your edit about the :hover opacity. What I suggest is that you change the styling to be more like this: `a > img:hover { visibility: hidden; }`

Comment: sorry my first comment was misleading. It's not quite what I want; I would like to achieve the hover effect seen here http://labs.sevenspark.com/

Comment: okay here is your solution using jQuery: `$("a > img").mouseenter(function() { $(this).fadeTo(.65, 400); }).mouseleave(function() { $(this).fadeTo(1, 400); });` You will have to come up with an IE fix though, since fadeTo doesn't work in IE. I can help you with that if you have trouble